# Combine a stateful application with stateless JWT

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

We have a FOSUserBundle login system authenticating via LDAP and the fr3d LDAP bundle. It behaves like a normal multiple page application using sessions. We also have several RESTful endpoints using the FOSRestbundle and normal sessions for authentication. However, we need to share a few end points with an external application.

We managed to implement JWT using the Lexik bundle. It returns a token just fine. However, I don't know the best way to let a user using our login form to get this token so their request can pass it along in the header or session. My question is how to allow a user to login to our application in a stateful manner, but also receive the JWT and pass it to the server on ajax requests. This way I can allow external clients to connect directly to the API. Below is my symfony2 security configuration, security.yml:

```
security:

    #erase_credentials: false

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [my_user_provider, fr3d_ldapbundle]

        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: secret, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

        my_user_provider:
            id: app.custom_user_provider

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/api/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        api_login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            provider: chain_provider
            anonymous: true
            stateless: false
            form_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                require_previous_session: false
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            provider: chain_provider
            stateless: false 
            lexik_jwt:
                throw_exceptions: true
                create_entry_point: true

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            form_login:
                # provider: fos_userbundle
                provider: chain_provider
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout: true
            anonymous: true
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_LIMS-BIOINFO}
```

EDIT:

Based on Kévin's answer I decided to implement a custom Twig extension to get the token for the logged in user on each page load:

AppBundle/Extension/JsonWebToken.php:

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Extension;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class JsonWebToken extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var JWTManagerInterface
     */
    private $jwt;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, JWTManagerInterface $jwt)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->jwt = $jwt;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'json_web_token';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            'json_web_token' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getToken')
        ];
    }

    public function getToken()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $token = $this->jwt->create($user);

        return $token;
    }
}
```

app/config/services.yml:

```
app.twig_jwt:
    class: AppBundle\Extension\JsonWebToken
    arguments: ["@service_container", "@lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig

```
<script>window.jsonWebToken = '{{ json_web_token() }}';</script>
```

app/Resources/modules/layout/app.js:

```
 var jsonWebToken = window.jsonWebToken;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + jsonWebToken);        
        } 
    });
```

So far this seems to be working well. It let's my external API users and internal application users share the same authentication methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JWT token must be stored client-side (and not in a cookie to prevent CSRF attacks), you can use the `create` method of the `lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager` service provided by LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle to generate a token after the login, then inject this token in a `<script>` tag in the generated HTML.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. I will give this a shot over the next couple of days and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Would injecting the token in a script tag not be a security issue? If for example a user saves his page after logging in, it would contain his jwt token in the html. He could then shares his saved page without knowing he is sharing his token.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i recently came across this same situation.
To generate the JWT I created a redirect listener

```
class RedirectListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    //the private variables go up here

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, TokenStorageInterface $sam, EntityManagerInterface $em, JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTTokenManager)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->sam = $sam;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->JWTTokenManager = $JWTTokenManager;
    }

    public function kernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $route = $request->get('_route');
        $routeParams = $request->get('_route_params');
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $matchApp = preg_match('/\/app/', $pathInfo);

        if ($event->isMasterRequest()) {
            if ($matchApp) {
                $token = $this->sam->getToken();
                if ($token) {
                    /** @var User $user */
                    $user = $token->getUser();
                    if($user instanceof User){
                        $token = $this->JWTTokenManager->create($user);
                        $this->twig->addGlobal('jwt', $token);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $event;
    }
}
```

This helped me get the JWT to my twig template (I used my base template to make sure it's present on every page)

```
    {% if jwt is defined %}
        <span class="hidden" id="jwt" data-jwt="{{ jwt ? jwt : 'null' }}"></span>
    {% endif %}
```

Now using autobahn JS I can subscribe using the JWT :

```
let jwt = $('#jwt').data('jwt');
let connection = new Connection({url:"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws", realm:"realm1"});
connection.onopen = (session) => {
    function onevent(args) {
        console.log("Event:", args[0])
    }
    session.subscribe(jwt, onevent);
}
connection.open();
```

Next the server can now receive messages with the JWT from the JS

```
 public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{

    $router = new Router();
    $realm = "realm1";

    $router->addInternalClient(new Pusher($realm, $router->getLoop()));
    $router->addTransportProvider(new RatchetTransportProvider("0.0.0.0", 8080));
    try{
        $router->start();
    } catch (\Exception $exception){
        var_dump($exception->getMessage());
    }

}
```

I now need to register a module for the router that will act as a listener and send messages back to the registered topic (JWT).

I'm not 100% there yet so any advice would be appreciated and I'll keep this updated as I go along.